# Fufilling my comittment on a converted SE site?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, commitment

I'm a beta user on [money.stackexchange.com](http://money.stackexchange.com) (still in private beta).  I was also a member of [www.BasicallyMoney.com](http://www.BasicallyMoney.com), and had asked and answered many questions on that.  Does that count toward my commitment or do I have to answer 10 more (I'm out of fresh questions)?

Comment: Both links refer to the same site. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Ladybug they moved the link.  `BasicallyMoney.com` was the existing SE1.0 site.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is, they will want to 'revitalize' the site with lots of new users with new questions.  Thus, they will want you to fulfill your commitment 'again' essentially.